# Polynomial in two variables Lipschitz on compact set in $R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

[I am trying to work out this textbook question about uniform continuity. Looking at the hint, it seems like they are evaluating the function on the line y=x. If this is the case, why? I am not sure about how to bound the derivative of this function since it is on $R^2$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYxxO.png)

Comment: You need to write up the problem here, at MSE, as that image will disappear in the sands of time.

Comment: The answer also depends on the norm on $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @Dap Could you please give me a hint as to how the norm on $R^2$ is used here?

Comment: @8elta3psilon: uniform continuity (or Lipschitz continuity) are defined in terms of distances, so the norm or metric matters. "If $\|(x,y)\|<\delta$ then" etc

Comment: @Dap But where I am stuck is relating that to $||p(x_1,y_1)-p(x_2,y_2)||$

Comment: @8elta3psilon: I am just commenting that your question is missing some info (as well as what zhw said)

Comment: @Dap that is the entire question as found in the textbook